# Controller VUsers configuration no repeat data

Tags: controller, loadrunner

I need your help ! I've built a LR script that do login, consult and logout but all of that in a single action.

The point is each iteration i need to login with a different account and can´t repeat because the system does not allow multiple logins, has anyone knows how do i need to configure Controller to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if the problem you are experiencing is not related to parameterizing user credentials in your script (you say it did work in Vugen) but rather due to accessing your system with concurrent users from your client with the same IP.

Try IP spoofing. I think that might help .. will work with HTML.

Tirza.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you want to create a parameter of the login username and password. 
Please consult the relevant documentation for your LR version on parameterizing the script.

Note that after adding the parameters you can tell the controller to cycle through all the possible values of that parameter.

I could give you a more exact answer if you would tell me the LR version and the script protocol.

For example, this: http://www.iloveloadrunner.com/2012/04/loadrunner-vugen-parameterization.html

is a good reference for version 11

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: Hi Boris, thank you for your answer !! LR version is 11.04 and my script uses just HTML protocol. I've did the script using parametrization, when i run the script at vugen with 9 iterations it runs fine but when i run using Controller all of than crash. I'll check the article that you sent if i configured correctly. Parameters: x = Always the same y = Different numebers (Next row: random | Update Value on: Each Iteration) Pwd = Always the same  Thank you ! Regards, Rodrigo F

Answer (score 0):

See your LoadRunner training material, parameterization module, for information on the use of parameters with the UNIQUE attribute.   This same information is also covered in the VUGEN users guide and the section on parameterization.